# Use Javascript to insert something in every table cell

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm addicted to jQuery and am having trouble using pure JavaScript to loop through every `<td>` on a page and inserting an `<input>`.  Can anyone help me out with this simple task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like jQuery then you should find [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) method fun to use to select DOM elements. You can try something like this to insert input into every `td` on a page:

```js
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

Array.prototype.slice.call(tds).forEach(function(td) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    td.appendChild(input);
});
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Of course instead of fancy `forEach` you can use old-good `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

And instead of `querySelectorAll('td')` there is also

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
```